# Read from command performance

Tags: perl

My goal is to do some regex and some processing on the data (line based) that comes out of a process. Since I've already got a bunch of tool in perl, I decided to use perl to solve my problem.

Let's say a process that output a large file for example :

cat LARGEFILE.txt | grep "A String"

Obviously the process I want to call is not "cat" but something that output a bunch of lines (typically 100 GB of data).

I had doubt about the performance of my perl program and I started to strip down code to the minimum. I realized that my problem might come from the way I read the output from the command in perl.

Here's my perl script :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

open my $fh, "cat LARGE.txt |";
while (<$fh>) {
        print $_ if $_ =~ qr/REGEX NOT TO BE FOUND/o;
}
```

I decided to compare my program with a simple bash command :

```
cat LARGE.txt | grep "REGEX NOT TO BE FOUND"
```

Results :

```
time cat LARGE.txt | grep "REGEX NOT TO BE FOUND"
real    0m0.615s
user    0m0.352s
sys     0m0.873s

time ./test.pl 

real    0m37.339s
user    0m36.621s
sys     0m1.766s
```

In my example, LARGE.txt file is about 1.3GB.

I understand that the perl solution might be slower than the `cat | grep` example, but I was not expecting that much difference.

Is there something wrong with my way of reading the output of a command ?

P.S. I use  perl v5.10.1 on a Linux box

Comment: Could you replace `open my $fh, "cat LARGE.txt |";` with `open my $fh, '<', 'LARGE.txt';` and try again?

Comment: @LeeDuhem I've did that and the result is similar. (36 seconds). However, I really need to get this from the output of a process, not from a file. I can't use temporary files. I guess I could use named pipes but I'd rather not as it adds complexity to my processes.

Comment: Well, I guess you need to do some profiling to find out the performance bottleneck in your case.

Comment: I am very suspicious about the times you are getting for `grep`. A hard disk average read speed rarely exceeds 150MB/s, meaning it should take 15s just to read a 2GB file.

Comment: I run the tests on SSD drives, I achieve ~ 400MB/s read performance. (https://gist.github.com/codingtony/3910630). To be fair, I retested and droped the cache before (sudo bash -c "echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches") running the cat | grep. The result real = 3 secs. However I rechecked the size of the file and it's 1.3GB not 2GB. My mistake, I will correct the question.

Comment: @LeeDuhem with strace I see that the read buffer is set to 4K. Which seem a bit small to me. When I try to modify it using setvbuf, I get : `setvbuf not implemented on this architecture`

Comment: @Tony You may want to take a look at [perlio](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html). However, you need to read from a pipe instead of a file, change the default PerlIO layer may not be helpful. Nevertheless, it may worth a try.

Comment: I get a ~2x speed increase by precompiling the regex: `my $regex = qr/REGEX NOT TO BE FOUND/o;` and in the loop, `print $_ if $_ =~ $regex;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try out sysread:

(stolen from: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=457046)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $filename = "test.txt";

die "filename not found\n" unless -f $filename;

my $size = -s $filename;
my $total_read = 0;

open my $fh, "<", $filename or die "can't open $filename\n";
binmode($fh);

my $bufsize = 8192; # typical size for i/o buffers
my ( $databuf, $readbuf, $nread );
while (( $nread = sysread( $fh, $readbuf, $bufsize )) > 0 ) {
    $databuf .= $readbuf;
    process_lines_from_buffer(\$databuf);
}
print "initial size: $size\n";

sub process_lines_from_buffer{
    ### to make it efficient do not use a named variable for the buffer
    return undef if ! defined $_[0];
    while (${$_[0]} =~ s!(.*?)\n!!){
        ### do your processing
        process_line(\$1);
    }
}
sub process_line {
    print ${$_[0]}."\n";
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I need to spawn a process and read the output from the process. I modified your script to open "cat LARGE.txt |" and it still works. It is faster, pretty much in par with "cat". However I need to extract the lines from the buffer, and handle case when a line is between to read calls. I need to process line by line. Is there anyway to tell perl to use sysread under the hood when using while (<$fh>) { } ? Tomorrow evening, if there is no better answer, I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: You could try to add binmode to your original script, it is forces a bit efficient processing (If I understand correctly the docs http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html)

Comment: You could reconstruct lines from buffer and process that. If you want to be really fast you could spawn a thread and process every line in that thread.

Comment: Thanks for your update, I feel this is a step in the right direction. Have you tried it ? I just did, and it looks like there is something wrong with the regex  `s!(.*?)\n!!is`. I've changed `process_line(\$1);` to `print "HERE\n";` and I never get there. Also I have the feeling that the code could have a memory problem  since all the data gets into `$databuf`. I have to play with streams larger than the available RAM.

Comment: I have used wrongly a refrence. The buffer gets emptied by the regular expression  i.e. every processed line gets removed.

Comment: Thanks, it works, I suspect there is some inefficiency with the regex that splits the lines, since it takes 45 seconds to complete. (even if I don't print anything i.e empty `process_line` sub). I'm accepting your answer since it's the one that got me closer to my goal.